# date picker in javascript

Tags: javascript, date, datepicker, mootools

I am getting no date picker in my web page but in fiddle it is coming, what i am missing?

http://jsfiddle.net/cBwEK/

It is coming fine in fiddle but i am getting nothing in my web page. I
 have written below scripts

The whole source code is here: http://www.monkeyphysics.com/mootools/script/2/datepicker

```
<html>
 <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>     
    <script type="text/javascript" src="datepicker.js"></script>      
    <script type="text/javascript" src="mootools-yui-compressed.js"></script>
    <script type="text/css" src="datepicker.css"></script>        
    <script type="text/javascript">           
        new DatePicker('.picker', {
            pickerClass: 'datepicker ',
            allowEmpty: true
        });           
    </script>        
 </head>
 <body>
     <label>Datepicker starting at and allowing no value:</label>
     <input name='date_allow_empty' type='text' value='' class='date picker' />
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try loading mootools **before** the datepicker script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to run your JavaScript code *after* the relevant elements exist in the DOM. Just move the script to the end of the page. Also, if the date picker script relies on MooTools, you need to put the datepicker include *after* the MooTools include. E.g.:

```
<html>
 <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>     
    <!-- FIRST CHANGE HERE, swapping the order of the script elements -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="mootools-yui-compressed.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="datepicker.js"></script>      
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="datepicker.css">
 </head>
  <body>
   <label>Datepicker starting at and allowing no value:</label>
   <input name='date_allow_empty' type='text' value='' class='date picker' />
   <!-- SECOND CHANGE HERE, moving your script to *after* the elements it operates on -->
   <script type="text/javascript">           
            new DatePicker('.picker', {
     pickerClass: 'datepicker ',
     allowEmpty: true
     });           
   </script>        
  </body>
</html>
```

[Live copy](http://jsbin.com/ofezog) | [source](http://jsbin.com/ofezog/edit#html)

There I've just moved *your* script, but you might move all the scripts down there [as the YUI people suggest](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html).

The reason it works in jsFiddle is that you have the fiddle set to load the JavaScript code from the `onload` event, which happens very late in the process; the DOM elements are there by then.

Comment: thanks T.J for your answer but i am still getting no date picker, i added your code but same problem, i need to move all scripts to end of body section except motools script?

Comment: @saroj: Yeah, I just noticed that when doing a live example (which I've now added to the answer). Glad that helped.

Comment: just one solution needed is while displaying days let's say for June month, also some days of may and also some days of july are displayed which i do n't want to display, i want to display only days of june, how it can be done?

Comment: yes i asked in a different question :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10381454/a-date-picker-in-javascript

Comment: ....any solution please : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10397240/date-picker-not-appearing-after-clicking-on-image

Answer (score 2):

Try to load the the DatePicker Initialization after the page load.

```
A good programmer always use View Source
```

If you would have seen Fiddle you would see:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    window.addEvent('load', function() {
        new DatePicker('.picker', {
             pickerClass: 'datepicker ',
            allowEmpty: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

That's because the HTML elements are not loaded and your scripts don't see them.