# Only display days of specific month in datepicker

Tags: javascript, date, datepicker, mootools

I have a date picker and it is displaying a date. But the problem is each month is showing some days of previous month and also some days of next month which I don't want to be displayed. I want that each month should display days of that particular month.

For example let's say Month **JUNE**, here some days of month **MAY** and also some days of month **JULY** are displayed, but i want that only days of `JUNE` should be displayed. How can I do it? I am trying but no result is coming.

Here is the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/cBwEK/

Comment: You've tagged this as jQuery, yet the code is MooTools?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan sorry code is MooTools

Comment: Always include the relevant code and markup **in the question itself**, don't just link. Why: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118392/add-stack-overfow-faq-entry-or-similar-for-putting-code-in-the-question

Comment: but why a -1 on the question??

Comment: @T.J.Crowder any solution to this question please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10381965/surprising-result-coming-in-java-servlet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the other month values invisible by adding:

```
​.datepicker .otherMonth {
    visibility: hidden;        
}
```

to your CSS.  See the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cBwEK/5/).

Comment: yes i got it, but can you please little bit design..if possible..actually extra space is coming below

Comment: I think that just happens when there are no days for the bottom row on the month you are viewing.  If you got rid of this, then when you switched months it would have to resize the picker, which wouldn't look great.