# surprising result coming in java servlet

Tags: java, date, servlets, datepicker

I am getting surprise result in java servlet. I am passing input parameter(a date) from a jsp to servlet like this:

```
 <input name='date_allow_empty' type='text' value='' class='date picker' />
```

Date picker is here: http://jsfiddle.net/cBwEK/

let's say i choosed : 05-04-2012, when i passed this date to servlet then i am getting:

```
1333620371
```

But i should get 05-04-2012 in servlet

```
Servlet:

  String t= request.getParameter("date_allow_empty");

  out.println(t); //displaying 1333620371 in stead of 05-04-2012
```

Why this type of result is being displayed in servlet?

Comment: I think (not very sure of it) you are getting the time in milliseconds since 1970, just set it as Date object and convert it into standard format.

Comment: @AurA ok but how to set it as Date object? Where should i modify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That value, `1333620371`, is the number of seconds since The Epoch (Jan 1st, 1970). To make a Java `Date` out of it, use the [`Date(long)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date%28long%29) constructor, which expects *milli*seconds since The Epoch (so you multiply by 1,000):

```
Date dt = new Date(value * 1000);
```

If you're getting the value as a `String`, you'll need to [`parseLong`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) it first, e.g.:

```
Date dt = new Date(Long.parseLong(value, 10) * 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the number of seconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT, see: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime()

To convert it to a java.util.Date object, simply use :

```
String t= request.getParameter("date_allow_empty");
Date theDate = new Date(Long.valueOf(t) * 1000);
```

(http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date(long))

EDIT : It is in seconds, not milliseconds :(

Comment: *"You're getting the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT..."* Clearly not, if it were milliseconds then `1333620371` would be Jan 16, 1970, at 10:27.